# Добавление рядов и колон в таблицу JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Задача состоит в том, чтобы при нажатии кнопки add создавался ряд и 4 колонки , и записывать туда данные из переменных. Вот что имеется на данный момент.

```js
var name;
var age;
var weekend;
var workday;
var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
var peopleAmount = prompt("Сколько людей вы хотите проанализировать?");
peopleAmount = parseInt(peopleAmount);

function dataToTable() {
  for (var i = 0; name !== null && i < peopleAmount; i++) {
    name = prompt('Имя человека? Если хотите закончить нажмите "Отмена"');
    age = prompt('Сколько лет человеку? ');
    age = parseInt(age);
    weekend = age * 116;
    workday = age * 275;
    if (name === null) {
      i += 1000;
    }
  }
  return name;
  return age;
  return weekend;
  return workday;
}

function addTable() {
  var table = document.getElementById('myTable');
  var tr = document.createElement('tr') * 4;
  var td = document.createElement('td') * 4;
  table.appendChild(tr);
  tr.appendChild(td);
}
```

```html
<table border="1" id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <th class="nameTitle">Name</th>
    <th class="ageTitle">Age</th>
    <th class="workdaysTitle">Workdays</th>
    <th class="weekendTitle">Weekends</th>
  </tr>
</table>
<input type="button" value="add" onclick="addTable();">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала вам нужно знать, что после вызова `return` выполнение функции прекращается. Поэтому каскад

```
return name;
return age;
return weekend;
return workday;
```

бессмысленен. Если вы хотите вернуть из функции несколько значений, то для этого нужно использовать какие-нибудь контейнеры: массивы или объекты.

Далее, попытка создать четыре объекта одним махом

```
var td = document.createElement('td') * 4;
```

конечно похвальна. Но в JS умножать можно только числа. А для размножения объектов люди используют циклы

```js
function dataToTable() {
  var peopleAmount = prompt("Сколько людей вы хотите проанализировать?");
  peopleAmount = parseInt(peopleAmount);
  var res = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < peopleAmount; i++) {
    var name = prompt('Имя человека? Если хотите закончить нажмите "Отмена"');
    if (name === null)
      break;
    var age = prompt('Сколько лет человеку? ');
    age = parseInt(age);
    res.push({
      name: name,
      age: age,
      weekend: age * 116,
      workday: age * 275
    });
  }
  return res;
}

function addTable() {
  var table = document.getElementById('myTable');
  var data = dataToTable();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    table.appendChild(tr);
    for (var fld in data[i]) {
      var td = document.createElement('td');
      tr.appendChild(td);
      td.innerText = data[i][fld];
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<table border="1" id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <th class="nameTitle">Name</th>
    <th class="ageTitle">Age</th>
    <th class="workdaysTitle">Workdays</th>
    <th class="weekendTitle">Weekends</th>
  </tr>
</table>
<input type="button" value="add" onclick="addTable();">
```